# LDAP Password reset does not respect the pwdhistory attribute

Tags: java, ldap, passwords, openldap, apache-directory

I'm using  Java - Apache Directory Client API for accessing Apache DS Ldap Server using ldapConnectionTemplate.

I'm trying to implement a feature which allows the user to reset/change the password. My password policy has a password history attribute value of 5. So user will not be able to use any of the previous 5 passwords.

When I'm using the modifyPassword method for changing the password(i.e. as a user by passing current and new password), it respects the password history policy. i.e I'm not allowed to use any of the previous 5 passwords and getting password exception as expected. But when using the reset option(i.e. - only new password), it does not honor the password policy. It accepts any value(including current one) and updates the password.

How to make the reset password scenario honor the password history policy? Any ideas, suggestions and solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the behaviour you desire is specified anywhere.

The idea of a 'reset' in the sense you mean is that the admin sets it to something known, tells the user what it is, and the `pwdReset` attribute is set to TRUE so that the user is forced to immediately change it on next login - which you have to enforce yourself by using the `PasswordPolicy` request control and inspecting any `PasswordPolicyResponse` for [`CHANGE_AFTER_RESET`](http://directory.apache.org/api/gen-docs/latest/apidocs/org/apache/directory/api/ldap/extras/controls/ppolicy/PasswordPolicyErrorEnum.html#CHANGE_AFTER_RESET).

There's no particular reason why the *admin* should be constrained by the `pwdHistory`, and anyway the user is going to be forced to change the password again anyway, at which time he *will* be constrained by `pwdHistory`.